# Unable to build .exe for Electron

Tags: reactjs, electron, package.json, electron-packager, mdbreact

I am trying to create .exe for my react web app for Windows using electron-installer-windows. It says that

> Error: No Description or ProductDescription provided. Please set either a description in the app's package.json or provide it in the this.options.

when I run `npm run setup`. Please find packge.json and error stack trace.

package.json

```
      {
    "name": "utility-core",
    "description": "Load bulk data to Fluent",
    "productDescription":"Test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "license": "ISC",
    "productName": "Fluent Bulk Import Utility",
    "author": {
      "name": "Zain Ul Abideen"
    },
    "private": true,
    "main": "public/electron.js",
    "homepage": "./",
    "dependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
      "axios": "^0.18.0",
      "babel-core": "6.26.0",
      "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
      "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
      "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
      "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
      "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
      "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
      "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
      "chalk": "1.1.3",
      "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
      "css-loader": "0.28.7",
      "dotenv": "4.0.0",
      "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
      "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
      "eslint": "4.10.0",
      "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
      "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
      "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
      "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
      "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
      "file-loader": "1.1.5",
      "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
      "jest": "20.0.4",
      "jquery": "^3.4.1",
      "mdbreact": "^4.15.0",
      "object-assign": "4.1.1",
      "papaparse": "^4.6.0",
      "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
      "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
      "promise": "8.0.1",
      "raf": "3.4.0",
      "react": "^16.4.1",
      "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.1",
      "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
      "react-file-reader": "^1.1.4",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.2.0",
      "react-spinners": "^0.4.6",
      "resolve": "1.6.0",
      "style-loader": "0.19.0",
      "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
      "universal-cookie": "^3.0.4",
      "url-loader": "0.6.2",
      "wait-on": "^3.2.0",
      "webpack": "3.8.1",
      "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
      "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
      "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node scripts/start.js",
      "build": "node scripts/build.js",
      "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
      "electron-dev": "concurrently \" cross-env BROWSER=none npm run start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
      "electron-pack": "build -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js",
      "preelectron-pack": "npm run build",
      "setup": "electron-installer-windows --src dist/fluent-bulk-import-utility-win32-x64/ --dest installers/"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
      "csv-loader": "^3.0.2",
      "electron": "^1.8.8",
      "electron-builder": "^20.44.4",
      "electron-installer-windows": "^2.0.0",
      "electron-packager": "^8.7.2"
    },
    "jest": {
      "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
      ],
      "setupFiles": [
        "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
      ],
      "testMatch": [
        "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
        "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
      ],
      "testEnvironment": "node",
      "testURL": "http://localhost",
      "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
        "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
      },
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
      },
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "web.js",
        "js",
        "json",
        "web.jsx",
        "jsx",
        "node",
        "mjs"
      ]
    },
    "babel": {
      "presets": [
        "env",
        "react-app"
      ],
      "plugins": []
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "build": {
      "extends": null,
      "appId": "com.example.utility-core",
      "files": [
        "build/**/*",
        "node_modules/**/*",
        "./public/electron.js"
      ],
      "directories": {
        "buildResources": "assets"
      }
    }
  }
```

Error stack

```
        Error: No Description or ProductDescription provided. Please set either a description in the app's package.json or provide it in the this.options.
        at SquirrelInstaller.generateOptions (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-installer-windows\src\installer.js:156:13)
        at module.exports (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-installer-windows\src\installer.js:241:19) Error: No Description or ProductDescription provided. Please set either a description in the app's package.json or provide it in the this.options.
        at SquirrelInstaller.generateOptions (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-installer-windows\src\installer.js:156:13)
        at module.exports (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-installer-windows\src\installer.js:241:19)
```

Mainly following the documents  given below:

https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-windows-installer/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-installer-windows

Answer (score 1):

The "author" the error is referring to is the one in electron/package.json not being defined

Make sure you repack before building the installer and after you define the author in electron/package.json

I'd also suggest to use electron-builder here's a link for the configuration
https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration